# Invoke a may not existed member function by template

Tags: c++, templates

How can I call a may-existing member function by template technology, I am not want to use virtual method, because the class is arbitrary.

For example:

```
class A {
    void setValue(int value);
};
```

How to define a template to call class `A`'s setValue if it existing, else do nothing.

The template is something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct call_if_exist {
    void invokeOrNot(T& a, int value){ // EXISTING: setValue
        a.setValue(value);
    }
}
template <typename T>
struct call_if_exist {
    void invokeOrNot(T& a, int value){ // NOT EXISTING: do nothing
    }
}
```

It's about invoking, not checking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a templated function if it exists, and something else otherwise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386183/how-to-call-a-templated-function-if-it-exists-and-something-else-otherwise)

Comment: possible duplicate of [compile-time conditional member function call in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363822/compile-time-conditional-member-function-call-in-c)

Comment: Doing a google search 'c++ template conditional call' yields plenty of results with useful answers.

Comment: There is a typo in your code: `invokeOrNot` has no open-brace bracket.

Comment: Thank you！Sorry, I not very familiar with editing code in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) to make a class template that [checks for the existence of a member function in a given class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10340974/1609356), and use the result as a boolean flag to specialize your template for the case when there is no function, and the case when the member function exists:

```
template<typename T , bool member_exists = has_set_value<T>::result>
struct call_if_exist;

template <typename T>
struct call_if_exist<T,true> {
    void invokeOrNot(T& a, int value){ // EXISTING: setValue
        a.setValue(value);
    }
}
template <typename T>
struct call_if_exist<T,false> {
    void invokeOrNot(T& a, int value){ // NOT EXISTING: do nothing
    }
}
```

---

### Edit: The `has_set_value` trait

```
template<typename T>
class has_set_value
{
    typedef struct{ char c[1]; } yes;
    typedef struct{ char c[2]; } no;

    template<typename U> static yes test(&U::set_value);
    template<typename U> static no  test(...);

public:
    static const bool result = sizeof( test<T>(NULL) ) == sizeof( yes );
};
```

This class is the typical example of the usage of SFINAE to check for the existence of a member (type or function) of a certain class.

First we define two typedefs, `yes` and `no`, which are used to **differentiate overload resolutions through the `sizeof` operator.**
The first overload of `test()` has **a pointer to the member function as parameter**, and the last is an overload which goal is to be called by **everything thats not a pointer to the member**. This is done through a variadic-function (Note the ellipsis), which can be used with any kind of parameter.

The point of the implementation is **even if the second overload can hold any parameter, the first is an explicit case for pointers to our member function.** So if the parameter could be a pointer to the function, **the call is resolved to the first function**, else its resolved to the second.

As I said before, we use the typedefs to differentiate the overload resolution through the `sizeof` operator: **Note that the first overload returns `yes` and the later returns `no`.** So if the size of the result type of the call to `test()` using a pointer (NULL) is equal to the size of `yes`, means that the overload is resolved to the first, **and the class passed as parameter (`T`) has a member function called `set_value`.**

[Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Dessign](http://f3.tiera.ru/other/DVD-009/Alexandrescu_A._Modern_C++_Design%5Bc%5D_Generic_Programming_and_Design_Patterns_Applied_(2001)(en)(271s).pdf) includes an example of this kind of trait in chapter two to [check if one type is implicitly convertible to other](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible).

Comment: Could you give more detail about has_set_value<T>::result? Sorry, i have no idea about implement that after i read the links you given.